# Batch File - Create Zip file with Command Line using the first part of the first file name

Tags: batch-file, 7zip

I have a folder of PDF files that have a consistent naming convention. I want to create a zip file of these PDF files but named the zip file using the portion of the file that is before the @ -- all of the files are the same in the front (it is the NTID of the user that created the pdf files).

As an example these are what the files might look like in the PDF output folder (there could be 100 files all that start with the same UserID before the @:

UserID@Carlos+Alberto+Mafra-+bribery-2019-05-16

UserID@MAJELA+HOSPITALAR+LTDA-+bribery-2019-05-16

(Ideally, I would also want the current date appended to the zip file)
The zip should be called UserID-2019-05-16.zip based on the example above.

This is the code I am trying to use but not having success...

I created a batch script using others suggestions for each step. but can't get it to work end to end.

```
FOR %%F IN ("C:\Users\SA-JJC-HCC_Ops\OneDrive - JNJ\workflows\TPIGoogle\pdf\*.pdf") DO (
 set filename=%%F
 goto next
)
:next
echo "%filename%"

set zipfile=%filename%
for /f "tokens=1 delims=@" %%a in ("%zipfile%") do (

)
cd "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\"
7z.exe" a "C:\Users\SA-JJC-HCC_Ops\JNJ\HCC&P Alteryx - Documents\EPiC\GoogleSearches\zip\" && %zipfile% && ".zip" "C:\Users\SA-JJC-HCC_Ops\OneDrive - JNJ\workflows\TPIGoogle\pdf\*.pdf"
```

One zip file with all the PDFs that are using the first part of the string from the file names in the PDF folder.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=@" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*@*-????-??-??.pdf" '
 ) DO (
 SET "pre=%%~a"
 SET "post=%%~nb"
 SET "post=!post:~-10!"
 IF DEFINED post ECHO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" a "%destdir%\!pre!-!post!.zip" "%sourcedir%\%%~a@%%~b"
 IF NOT DEFINED post ECHO SKIP "%%~a@%%~b"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used the variablenames `pre` and `post` to ensure that the names used in this process are not keywords like the more logical `date`.

Read a list of all filenames matching the pattern `*@*-????-??-??.pdf` in the source directory, tokenising on `@`. Assign the userid to `%%a` and thence to `pre` and the "name" part of the dregs of the actual filename to `post`, then select only the last 10 characters of `post` using delayed-expansion.

There is an opportunity here to further process `post` to check whether it truly fits the pattern for a date, if that is required. That routine may return `post` either unmolested or *empty*. If it's not empty then construct the required `7z` command (you may wish to add `-tzip`) and `echo` this for verification - remove the `echo` to actuate the `7z` compression. If `post` *is* emptied by a pattern-checking routine, then the filename will simply be reported as having been skipped.

Comment: I made a slight adjustment to the formatting of the pdf files that end up in the source folder. Tried to adjust the code to tokenize for # instead of @ (as @ is not included as part of the file name with the user email address) 

email@company.com#-12345John+Doe-bribery-2019-05-17.pdf

Any suggestions?  when I updated for tokenizing by # the code did not work.

Comment: Ah! the dread "did not work" problem. Did you change *all* of the `@` to `#` - in the `dir` line, and the `if [not] defined` lines as well as the `delims` clause?

Answer (score 0):

If it is indeed current date you want to append to the end of the zip file, then we need to get the non locale dependent date and time. This will then copy each of the pdf files that starts with UserID to a zip with a date of the day you run the script `UserID-2019-05-17` :

```
@echo off
set "outDir=C:\Users\SA-JJC-HCC_Ops\JNJ\HCC&P Alteryx - Documents\EPiC\GoogleSearches\zip\"
set "inDir=C:\Users\SA-JJC-HCC_Ops\OneDrive - JNJ\workflows\TPIGoogle\pdf\"
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in ('wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE') do (
    if ".%%i."==".LocalDateTime." set mydate=%%j
)
set mydate=%mydate:~0,4%-%mydate:~4,2%-%mydate:~6,2%

for %%a in (*.pdf) do for /f "delims=@" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d %%a') do (
    "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" a "%outDir%%%i-%mydate%.zip" "%inDir%%%~a"
)
```

If in fact you want to append the date of the filename instead (In other words create Zip files for each file with a different date as well as matching userid):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "outDir=C:\Users\SA-JJC-HCC_Ops\JNJ\HCC&P Alteryx - Documents\EPiC\GoogleSearches\zip\"
set "inDir=C:\Users\SA-JJC-HCC_Ops\OneDrive - JNJ\workflows\TPIGoogle\pdf\"
for %%a in (*.pdf) do for /f "tokens=1,* delims=@" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d %%a') do (
    set fdate=%%~nj
    set fdate=!fdate:~-10!
    echo "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" a "%outDir%%%i-!fdate!.zip "%inDir%%%~a"
)
```